# /usr/bin vs /usr/local/bin on Linux

Tags: filesystems, binary

Why are there so many places to put a binary in Linux? There are at least these five:

1. `/bin/`
2. `/sbin/`
3. `/usr/bin/`
4. `/usr/local/bin/`
5. `/usr/local/sbin/`

And on my office box, I do not have write permissions to some of these.

What type of binary goes into which of these `bin`s?

Comment: You forgot `/usr/sbin/`.

Comment: And `~/bin/` for personal stuff.

Comment: There are fewer places nowadays, since `/bin` was merged with `/usr/bin` and `/sbin` was merged with `/usr/sbin` – see [The Case for the /usr Merge](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/).

Comment: Related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/308045/differences-between-bin-sbin-usr-bin-usr-sbin-usr-local-bin-usr-local/308048

Comment: @Calmarius, What? shouldn't you use `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: @Pacerier  ~/bin is for the current user only. For example in multiuser Linux servers where you are not an admin that's the only way to "install" stuff for yourself.

Comment: @Calmarius Personal binaries go in `~/.local/bin`

Answer (score 898, accepted):

1. `/bin` (and `/sbin`) were intended for programs that needed to be on a small `/` partition before the larger `/usr`, etc. partitions were mounted.  These days, it mostly serves as a standard location for key programs like `/bin/sh`, although the original intent may still be relevant for e.g. installations on small embedded devices.
2. `/sbin`, as distinct from `/bin`, is for system management programs (not normally used by ordinary users) needed before `/usr` is mounted.
3. `/usr/bin` is for distribution-managed normal user programs.
4. There is a `/usr/sbin` with the same relationship to `/usr/bin` as `/sbin` has to `/bin`.
5. `/usr/local/bin` is for normal user programs *not* managed by the distribution package manager, e.g. locally compiled packages. You should not install them into `/usr/bin` because future distribution upgrades may modify or delete them without warning.
6. `/usr/local/sbin`, as you can probably guess at this point, is to `/usr/local/bin` as `/usr/sbin` to `/usr/bin`.

In addition, there is also `/opt` which is for monolithic non-distribution packages, although before they were properly integrated various distributions put Gnome and KDE there.  Generally you should reserve it for large, poorly behaved third party packages such as Oracle.

Comment: I think this answer does a great job of clarifying a common set of conventions, but this post from Rob Landley is a really great read if you want insight into the nonsense... http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2010-December/074114.html

Comment: http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml for the canonical current reference. The link by @kojiro is outdated and doesn't have the new spec.

Comment: Where do I put a bin I downloaded from the internet? From your description it sounds like it should go in /usr/local/bin or /usr/bin. Is /usr/bin something I should never manually touch, and let only the package manager play with?

Comment: @DidierA. put it in `~/bin` and add that directory to your PATH as a user... Thanks for the note, I deleted my seriously outdated comment.

Comment: What's the hierarchy as far as precedence is concerned? I have `gcc` in `/usr/bin` for instance, and then I just compiled and installed gcc-7.2 from source and `make install` put it into `/usr/local/bin` and now gcc-7.2 seems to take precedence when I call `gcc` from the command-line. This also makes me wonder....if I want to use my old gcc-4.8 instead of gcc-7.2 how do I do it?

Comment: I found the answer to the first part of my question here: https://superuser.com/a/238993/425838. Precedence is based on order in the system `PATH` variable, and `echo $PATH` for me shows `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`, which means that executables in `/usr/local/bin` take precedence over the ones in `/usr/bin` which take precedence over the ones in `/bin`.

Comment: @kojiro Also, `~/bin` is usually automatically added to your PATH by `~/.profile` if and only if it exists. So it won't be in your PATH immediately after you first create `~/bin` but it should be automatically added to your PATH each time you log in in the future. `cat ~/.profile` should show a conditional statement for this.

Answer (score 133):

I recommend taking a look at the file system hierarchy man page:

```
man hier
```

which is also available online, for instance: http://linux.die.net/man/7/hier. 
Relevant portions have been copied below. 
Depending on your system, it may say something different.

> ### Name
>
>   hier - description of the file system hierarchy
>
> #### Description
>
>   A typical Linux system has, among others, the following directories:
>   `/bin`
>     This directory contains executable programs which are needed
>       in single user mode and to bring the system up or repair it.
>   `/sbin`
>     Like
>     `/bin`
>     , this directory holds commands needed to boot the system,
>       but which are usually not executed by normal users.
>   `/usr/bin`
>     This is the primary directory for executable programs. 
>       Most programs executed by
>               normal users which are not needed for booting or for repairing the system and
>               which are not installed locally
>       should be placed in this directory.
>   `/usr/local/bin`
>     Binaries for programs local to the site.
>   `/usr/local/sbin`
>     Locally installed programs for system administration.
>   `/usr/sbin`
>     This directory contains program binaries for system administration
>       which are not essential for the boot process, for mounting
>     `/usr`
>     ,
>       or for system repair.

Comment: This doesn't answer the user's question.

Comment: The man page does contain an entry for each of the bin directories, explaining what goes into them, which was one of the questions.

Comment: @BillyONeal Probably a better answer than others because it does answer the question, moreover gives a quick reference command as well.

Answer (score 47):

The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#Directory_structure) entry in Wikipedia helped me answer the same question when I had it, plus it has a very explanatory table.

Excerpt from that page<sup>1</sup>:

> ```
> /bin        Essential command binaries that need to be available in single user mode; for all users, e.g., cat, ls, cp.
> /usr/bin    Non-essential command binaries (not needed in single user mode); for all users.
> /usr/local  Tertiary hierarchy for local data, specific to this host. Typically has further subdirectories, e.g., bin, lib, share
> /usr/sbin   Non-essential system binaries, e.g., daemons for various network-services.
> /sbin       Essential system binaries, e.g., fsck, init, route.
> ```

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Retrieved on June 19, 2019; [permalink](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard&oldid=901110256).</sub>

Answer (score 24):

The `sbin` directories contains programs which are generally system administration only.  Programs for regular users should never go in them.

A few programs are needed during startup, and end up in `/bin/` or `/sbin/`.  These must be available before file systems are mounted. Things like `mount`, and `fsck` that are required to check and mount files systems must be there.

Most packaged programs end up in `/usr/bin/` and `/usr/sbin/`.  These may be on a file system other than the root file system.  In some cases they may be on a network mounted drive.

Local programs and scripts belong in `/usr/local/bin/` and `/usr/local/sbin/`.  This identifies them as clearly non-standard, and possibly only available on site.

For further explanation try running the command `man hier` which should provide a description of the recommended file system hierarchy for your distribution.  You may also want to read about the [File System Hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) on Wikipedia

Comment: +1 A really concise explanation if top is a little too much.

Comment: "Local programs and scripts belong in /usr/local/bin/ and /usr/local/sbin/" - You mean local programs as in "not at all part of the OS, but I decided to install them and want to use them"?

Answer (score 17):

In the 1970s, UNIX had all official executables in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` was a location beneath the users home directories (e.g. `/usr/dmr`) that was available for any user to store own binaries that might have been of interest for others as well.

The result of this open `/usr/bin` was a junk yard of undocumented software and so Stephen Bourne wrote a cron script that checked for new binaries every night and removed all binaries that did not have a documentation or that have been updated without updating their documentation as well.

In the late 1970s, `/usr/bin` was integrated into the OS base distribution and people started to use `/usr/local/bin` for the purpose of the previous open `/usr/bin`.

After a while, sysadmins used `/usr/local/bin` to store non-local software that was imported from the network (e.g. the USENET) and as UNIX companies did not like to repeat the same mistake as with `/usr/bin` again, there was a file system hierarchy conference around 1987 where all UNIX companies agreed to give up `/usr/local/bin` and to use `/opt/<vendor>/bin` instead.

Unfortunately, Linux distros did not follow this decision....

Comment: While very interesting,  none of this even tries to answer the question asked which was not about `/opt` and not about UNIX but about Linux. This is like answering "Why do cars have 4 wheels?" with "Bicycles have 2! Sadly, cars don't." which doesn't help the OP understand why cars have 4.

Comment: If you are unable to use the given explanation as an explanation to the background of Linux and the fact that Linux likes to mimic UNIX , you may be missing the needed background.

Comment: Interesting, but something I get confused on and which maybe is also only historical. Today, downloading a bin online, and a company bin isn't very different. If Joe Blow makes a program and I download it, why not put it in /opt/JowBlow/bin instead of /usr/local/bin. Is it a matter of trusted provider versus untrusted? It doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: I wish I had known this 'exact' history a few years back. a) I wondered why AIX avoided /usr/local, uses /opt/IBM and /opt/ibm and bullfreeware uses /opt/freeware - and why I SHOULD have used a different path (not just /opt/*sbin). As to semi-relevance with Linux - better GNU tools - the default --prefix in auto-tools is /usr/local. Too bad autotools (automake, autoconf, etc. do not follow ... . But we all survive and learn where the distrub. || vendors put their programs.