# How to run Dropbox daemon in background?

Tags: daemon, dropbox

I'm using Debian 6 and Dropbox. I followed [these commands](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) to install it.

When I run `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` — Dropbox works and stuff. Problem is that when I close terminal or, even worse — reboot, Dropbox stops working and I need to run that daemon again.

How can I have the computer automatically start that daemon in the background?

Comment: Have you tried the python script linked below on that same website? It seems to be targeted to controlling the daemon. (I don't have access to a debian-based machine ATM to try it myself though).

Comment: Perhaps `nohup`? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56495/whats-the-difference-between-running-a-program-as-a-daemon-and-forking-it-into

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you're running the daemon from your own account, start it at boot time with [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Run `crontab -e` to edit your [crontab](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=crontab&sektion=5) file and add the line

```
@reboot ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Comment: While this would work, ideally it would be best to create the service script within `/etc/init.d/` utilizing the skeleton script that is contained within. You can then add the `service dropbox start` to the cron on reboot and still have the ability to stop the service and restart it.

Comment: @sparticvs - Will dropbox not run as root if you put it in init.d? dropbox can be configured to run per user basis. Can the dropboxd be shared between users using different dropbox accounts?

Comment: @LordLoh. good point.  However you could change to who you want to run as.  I did find [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dropbox#Run_as_daemon_with_systemd) resource. Looks new.

Comment: @LordLoh. @sparticvs I think there is a solution to the `init.d` running as root problem. I posted an answer of my own, but the solution at http://pixeldust.wikidot.com/linode-setup%3adropbox seems to work well.

Answer (score 15):

run the command in this way:

```
($HOME/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd &)&
```

this will detach the process from tha actual terminal and put it in real background.

You will still have to start it back up manually after a reboot, though.

Answer (score 14):

Here is my solution. This is on Debian 8.

Install Dropbox as per standard instructions. So far, I've only got one user connected, I don't know if this will work with multiple users as dropbox seems to register the machine and not the linux user account. If you know how to get multiple user accounts on one server working let us know.

[https://www.dropbox.com/en_GB/install?os=lnx](https://web.archive.org/web/20190219090359/http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli)

Then install the python control script [instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20190219090359/http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli) but put it in /usr/bin and not your home directory bin.

Create file /lib/systemd/system/dropbox@.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Dropbox as a system service user %i

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dropbox start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/dropbox stop
User=%i
Group=%i
# 'LANG' might be unnecessary, since systemd already sets the
# locale for all services according to "/etc/locale.conf".
# Run `systemctl show-environment` to make sure.
Environment=LANG=en_US.utf-8

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable the service for user fred:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable dropbox@fred.service
```

Then start the service:

```
$ sudo systemctl start dropbox@fred.service
```

Comment: I like your answer, just a couple things I change. I'd add `After=network.target` under `[Unit]` and put the python file in `/usr/local/bin` per http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux

Comment: This answer ammended by Northstrider's comment should be part of the official documentation provided by Dropbox.

Comment: What's the difference between `dropbox` and `dropboxd` as provided in the distribution?

Answer (score 5):

You can also run as a daemon by doing `daemon $HOME/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`.

This has the advantage that if you additionally pass the `-n/--name` flag, you can use `daemon --[running|restart|stop] -n <name>` to control the process.

Perhaps someone else can chip in on how best to get daemons started using `daemon` to run at startup...

Answer (score 4):

You can find [Debian and Ubuntu init.d scripts](https://github.com/carlossg/puppet-dropbox/tree/carlos/files/etc/init.d), just copy to /etc/init.d/dropbox and customize with user name.

Enable in debian with `chkconfig --add dropbox`. Then run as any other service.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution for Linux distributions using Upstart 1.4 and higher.

Save the contents below into a configuration file under `/etc/init`, for example: `/etc/init/db_user.conf`:

```
# Dropbox upstart script for user db_user, db_user can be replaced by anything you like.

description "Dropbox db_user"
author "myth384"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

setuid db_user
# The next two lines are optional. I use these to be able to share the 
#   Dropbox using Samba. Within group shareusers are all Samba users.
# setgid shareusers
# umask 0002

# The next line is necessary to be able to synchronise files with non-ASCII characters.

env LANG="en_US.UTF-8"     
exec /home/db_user/.dropbox-dist/dropbox
```

To start up the daemon without rebooting:

```
sudo start db_user
```

**NOTE:** By uncommenting the setgid line it is not necessary to set the setgid flag on the `.dropbox.cache` folder as indicated by other sources on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here:

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/131973-dropbox-headless-workstation?page=1#entry-6076539

A user mentioned:

> Just thought I'd mention:
>
> (a) the latest distributions seem to make this fairly straightfoward,
>   just run `dropbox start` from the command line, BUT (b) watch out for
>   logging in and out with X11 forwarded.
>
> I've set up a lot of Bash aliases for connecting to various machines,
>   and they all include the `-X` option to forward X11 packets.  Because
>   of this, Dropbox kept dying on my on logout, even running it under
>   `screen` and with `nohup`.  Apparently, having X11 forwarded was causing
>   Dropbox to connect the dbus process on my local machine rather than on
>   the remote machine; so, when I broke the connection, Dropbox was
>   seeing dbus as having terminated and thus was terminating itself.
>
> Just FYI, as this stumped me for a bit.  The key was that I was having
>   to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> even after logging out / running `exit`
>   on the remote machine.  Apparently, SSH was keeping the session open, even
>   though I had exited Bash, because of the remaining open connection.

The solution is simple even if one (for some reason) wants to keep ssh-ing with the `-X`: before launching Dropbox you should "break" the forwarding for example doing:

```
$ unset DISPLAY
```

If this is done in a Bash script the forwarding is "broken" just inside the script but once this is executed the 'terminal' is still forwarding.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `screen`:

`screen -dmS ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`

This will start it as a daemon and in detached mode.

You would then have to write your own init.d script to have it run as service this way and add a line after `#!/bin/bash` for `chkconfig` and add the necessary run levels, such as 2, 3, 4, 5. Different distributions have different run levels so you'd have to check this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fairly nice way to add this to `init.d` described [here](http://pixeldust.wikidot.com/linode-setup%3adropbox). You have to add which users you want Dropbox to start for to the init script (easy enough), and when the system boots, it will start the Dropbox daemon for each of those users.

The only thing to note is that they specify `DAEMON=.dropbox-dist/dropbox` which I believe is incorrect. The author forgot the `d` at the end of that — it should be `DAEMON=.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be useful for all Linux distros, but in CentOS 7, from **Applications/System Tools/** menu, open '**Startup Applications**'. Then click Add, and enter this command:

```
/home/username/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

or

```
/home/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

[image]

Comment: @roaima thanks for your judgment. Which other solution? I just posted the solution which worked for me.

Comment: Cool, this is what worked for me. Simple and straightforward. Cron and some of the other solutions described did not.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following lines to the end of my .profile file. I prefer to have the computer boot at terminal. However, if I start X11 after this, the dropbox applet is not displayed on the system tray.

```
dropbox running
rv=$?
if [ $rv -eq 0 ]; then
    dropbox start;
fi
```

Comment: Assuming you really do mean `[ $rv -eq 0]` (and not `[ $rv -ne 0 ]`) you could simplify all that with `dropbox running && dropbox start`

Answer (score 0):

This site seems to have complete information on how to install and configure dropbox on Linux, including downloading and installing the CLI, creating soft links outside of dropbox, and running dropbox as a daemon. The latter provides an init.d script that will enable `dropboxd` to be controlled with `service` and `chkconfig`.

http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/install-dropbox-centos-gui-required

Answer (score 0):

download the script provided by dropbox
https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py
and run

```
python dropbox.py start
```

If you don't have python you will need pyhon to run this

Answer (score 0):

**1- install Dropbox** (reference: https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux):

32 bits:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -
```

64-bit:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

**2- Execute** (you have to execute at least one time, to log in Dropbox)

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

**3- Download this script:**

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py
mv download?dl=packages%2Fdropbox.py dropbox.py
mv dropbox.py ~/bin/dropbox.py
chmod 755 ~/bin/dropbox.py
```

You can use this command to get help about the script:

```
~/bin/dropbox.py help
```

**4- Set autostart**

```
~/bin/dropbox.py autostart y
~/bin/dropbox.py start
~/bin/dropbox.py status
```

As mentioned by @Zac there are a good explanation about each step here:
http://pixeldust.wikidot.com/linode-setup%3adropbox

Answer (score -1):

The solution is as other python programs :

```
shell$ nohup ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd &
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the best way is to create a new file in /usr/bin with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

save and name it "dropbox". Now you can run from console in background or create a shortcut in your menu/desktop

Comment: This is incorrect as it would just run in the foreground. You would have to still do `dropbox &` to send it to the background. Additionally if the terminal connection is ended, then the Hangup signal will kill the process.