# Difference between process in background and daemon

Tags: process, daemon, background-process

What is technically the difference of a process that started in foreground and was manually put into background and a daemon? Do they have different properties?

Comment: Related Question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56495/whats-the-difference-between-running-a-program-as-a-daemon-and-forking-it-into?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a look at the definition of a [Daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29), which tells you what the properties of a daemon are, so biggest ones are:

- No Controlling Terminal - STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR associated with starting terminal are redirected.
- Parent Process is set to `init`
- [Daemon is a Process Group Leader.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group)

Comment: So daemons need not have their own sessions, per se?

Comment: @jiggunjer You mean a user interactive session?

Comment: I thought every process had a SID, a session ID, `ps` displays it.

Comment: @jiggunjer What are you talking about?

Comment: A process is part of a session, yes?

Comment: @jiggunjer Can you defined what you mean by session?