# How can I pipe commands to any terminal?

Tags: terminal, pipe, tty, command, fifo

I often use more than one terminal (or terminal emulator) at a time; and while in X I can copy-paste commands, besides not being very practical, it obviously does not work on the real TTY. The first idea that occurs to me is something alike:

```
command > /dev/sometty
```

Unfortunately, the `command` is run **before** it is piped, and no tricks like `` echo `command` `` will work, no matter how many weird bash characters (`$`, `` ` ``, `"`, etc.) are there. So `/dev/sometty` simply gets some text.

The problem is that, sometimes, it is even worth for I to pipe those commands into a file, make it executable, etc., or shortly: making a script and running it from the appropriate terminal. But that is a lot of work. I've been thinking of making a script to make these files, for an instruction:

```
termpipe -e "command1\ncommand2\"command 1 argument\\n(s)\"" -t /dev/sometty
```

it would do something like:

1. pipe the commands to, say, `/tmp/termpipe-20140208-153029-1.sh`
2. make the file executable
3. run the file in the appropriate terminal
4. delete the script when it is done executing

AFAIK, the problem is in **3.**: this doesn't solve any problem, as I'd need another `termpipe` instance to run the first on the appropriate terminal. And one for that one. And another for that, *ad infinitum*. **So this cannot work.** Or can it?...

The solution could be to use a named pipe per terminal, and when each starts, a script would tell the pipe to forward anything it receives to the terminal, and then to execute it (like a sort of *daemon*).

I think this might work but I don't know how to set up the initial script. How can I? **How can I tell the FIFO to give piped commands for the respective terminal to run?** I don't know much Bash, so I'd appreciate full explanations.

Comment: Use `screen` or `tmux` (which have keyboard based copy pasting). On Linux, you can also use gpm to do copy-pasting with the mouse.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, thanks, I didn't know `tmux` could do that. But isn't there any way for what I suggested work?

Comment: @Stephane, I've been searching, andit turns out what I was thinking works! Now I just need a way for my script to start whenever a terminal starts. Maybe using `cron`... But that's another question...

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. What does “Unfortunately, the command is run before it is piped”? There isn't even a pipe here, there's a redirection, and it happens before the command starts. Please explain what you mean by piping, or better, use standard terminology.

Comment: @Gilles, considering `command > /dev/sometty` to be `command | tee /dev/sometty` isn't that `|` an [unnamed pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe)? Sorry if this is an innapropriate name, it's what I've always heard.

Comment: @JMCF125 `|` creates a pipe. `>` doesn't. And even if I interpret “redirection” when you wrote “pipe”, I have no idea what you're asking: `command >/dev/sometty` does redirect the output of the command to another terminal.

Comment: @Gilles, it redirects the **output**. I was looking for something to redirect as **input**, and then interpret it in the target. Compare my solution below, `echo "command" > tty3pipe` (after the scripting before), with `command > /dev/tty3`. How can I make this clearer? (note: this is not a void question, it's real asking for improvement; if an expert doesn't understand my question, then there's something wrong with the way I wrote it)

Comment: So it's an interactive command? Can you give an example? Did you try `command </dev/tty3 >/dev/tty3 2>/dev/tty3`? (If this dialog gets any longer, please consider continuing in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux).)

Comment: @Gilles, I didn't, I remember people in Stack Overflow writing this to not be possible! (at least with usual `>` and `<`) Thanks! But that does do the same as what I got below, only with colours by default, unlike my solution. Why is that? May you post an answer please?

Comment: @Gilles, ah, now I see... So that makes the command go to `/dev/tty3` for input, output, and error messages, right? I can put that as an answer, but I don't want to steal your idea. Maybe one could make a script to avoid writing `/dev/tty3` thrice. In fact, consider it done.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking. I stumbled in the dark and seem to have found something that satisfies you, but I don't know if it really answers the question (and in fact I suspect it won't work — as I said, if there's a shell or other program already running on `/dev/tty3`, and you run another program getting input from `/dev/tty3`, they will compete for input).

Comment: @Gilles, I'm supposing nothing is being inputed/outputed in `/dev/tty3`. An example use would be: I find a long command in the internet that does what I want. I was already on the directory I am supposed to be to run the command in `/dev/tty3`. But I can't copy it to there. Sure, I can do `pwd > /dev/pts/0`, but I'll have to copy the directory name and `cd` there **before** I copy the other command. Giving the command for `/dev/tty3` to take care of is just easier.

Comment: @JMCF125 If I understand your last comment correctly, then what I proposed doesn't do it. The command is executed in the current directory of the shell it was typed in. It seems you want the command to be executed **by the shell that is running in another terminal**, not just with its input and output connected to another terminal. Is that it? (You may want to read [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126))

Comment: @Gilles, damn it, I was in the same directory in both when testing! You're right, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Gilles, thanks, but I already read that. Though I use "terminal" as a catch-all term for TTYs and pseudo-TTYs (terminal emulators). BTW, learning a bit about `sed`, I got my solution below automatized! Without `cron`! I will post it ASAP.

Answer (score 5):

Following [this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash), one can very well make that last plan of yours work. For the command to-be-sent not to be processed by the shell, it has to be in the form of a string when reaches the pipe (thus `echo "command"`, not `` echo `command` ``). Then it has to be read by a background process ([alike](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56495/whats-the-difference-between-running-a-program-as-a-daemon-and-forking-it-into) a *daemon*, but not necessarily) started in the appropriate terminal. It should be [eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786149/execute-command-as-a-string-in-bash)uated by the same process.

But it is *boiler-platey* to have a script per pipe. So let's generalize making a script as `term-pipe-r.sh` (don't forget to `chmod +x` it!):

```
#!/bin/bash

pipe=$1                     # the pipe name is the first argument
trap 'rm -f "$pipe"' EXIT     # ignore exit and delete messages until the end

if [[ ! -p $pipe ]]; then   # if the pipe doesn't exist, create it
    mkfifo $pipe
fi

while true                  # cycle eternally..
do
    if read line <$ pipe; then
        if [[ "$line" == 'close the term-pipe pipe' ]]; then
            break
            # if the pipe closing message is received, break the while cycle
        fi

        echo                # a line break should be used because of the prompt 
        eval $line          # run the line: as this script should be started
    fi                          # in the target terminal, 
done                            # the line will be run there.

echo "<pipe closing message>"   # custom message on the end of the script
```

So say you want `/dev/tty3` to receive commands: just go there, do

```
./term-pipe-r.sh tty3pipe &     # $1 will be tty3pipe (in a new process)
```

And to send commands, from **any terminal** (even from itself):

```
echo "command" > tty3pipe
```

or to run a file there:

```
cat some-script.sh > tty3pipe
```

Note this piping ignores files like `.bashrc`, and the aliases in there, such as `alias ls='ls --color'`. Hope this helps someone out there.

### Edit (note - advantage of non-*daemon*):

Above I talked about the pipe reader not being a *daemon* necessarily, but in fact, I checked the [differences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56495/whats-the-difference-between-running-a-program-as-a-daemon-and-forking-it-into), and it turns out it is way better to be a mere background process in this case. Because this way, when you close the terminal, an `EXIT` signal (`SIGHUP`, `SIGTERM`, or whatever) is received by the script as well, and the pipe is deleted then (see the line starting with `trap` in the script) automatically, avoiding a useless process and file (and maybe others if there were such redirecting to the useless pipe).

### Edit (automation):

Still, it is boring to have to run a script you (I, at least) probably want most of the time. So, let's automatize it! It should [start](https://coderwall.com/p/u003pa) in any terminal, and one thing all of them read is `.bashrc`. Plus, it sucks to have to use `./term-pipe-r.sh`. So, one may do:

```
cd /bin # go to /bin, where Bash gets command names
ln -s /directory/of/term-pipe-r.sh tpr  # call it tpr (terminal pipe reader)
```

Now to run it you'd only need `tpr tty3pipe &` in `/dev/tty3` whenever you'd want. But why do that when you can have it done automatically? So this should be added to `.bashrc`. But wait: how will it know the pipe name? It can base the name on the TTY (which can be know with the `tty` command), using [simple](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Sed.html) REGEX's in `sed` (and [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903180/how-to-use-sed-without-a-file-with-an-env-var) [tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-can-i-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash)). What you should add to `~/.bashrc` will then be:

```
pipe="$(sed 's/\/dev\///' <<< `tty` | sed 's/\///')pipe"
                # ^^^- take out '/dev/' and other '/', add 'pipe'
tpr $pipe &     # start our script with the appropriate pipe name
```

Comment: I will update this to run the script on start-up for every terminal ASAP.

Comment: I see as @Gilles referred, if the target terminal is running something (with input, output and errors displayed there), there may be a problem. Say, with `startx`, there's simply no shown output of the directed command; but it can be much worse. I will try to address to that problem ASAP.

Comment: @ChrisDown, thanks, now I fixed it in my computer as well. I didn't notice the mistake (still a newbie in Bash), just forked it from [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash), where it is wrong originally.

Comment: This works fantastically on the ksh .profile on AIX! This will be very handy in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Vim's variant. Vim should be the default editor.

1. Pick a long command from the history, using up/down arrows. 
   I have chosen this:`echo "one two three" > new_file.txt`
2. Press `Ctrl + x` `Ctrl + e` combination. It will open our long command inside Vim. Press `Ctrl + g`, for showing the temporary file name in the bottom of the vim window. In my case it is `/tmp/bash-fc.230BC2`
3. Go to another **tty**, type `vim /tmp/bash-fc.230BC2` (using filename autocomplete, of course). It will tell you "Swap file  already exist" - press `O`, for open read only.
4. Then, inside vim, you are needed the next key sequence: `y$ : ! Ctrl+r " Enter` 
    **Explanation**:

   - `y$` - copy all characters in the line, except trailing newline.
   - `:` - go to the command-line mode
   - `!` - execute command with shell
   - `Ctrl+r "` - paste the copied line to the command line.
   - `Enter` - execute command

I should mention, that all this key sequence can be mapped to one keystroke, by `.vimrc` file edit.

It is done - command was copied from one tty to another and executed.