# Run an X11 command from a different console

Tags: x11, console

On my Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine compiz freezes often. I usually swtich to tty1 and kill the process, then switch back to tty7 and, if I can see a terminal window, I run `compiz --replace &` in it.
But there are times when I don't see any terminal window, and right clicking on the desktop doesn't give any menu so I can open one and I have to restart lightdm service. This is work blocking.

My question is: how can I run `compiz --replace &` or any other command from a different tty on tty7?

I read this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194293/how-to-send-terminal-command-to-a-tty-terminal), but I don't know how to make tmux connect to a different tty on my machine, and the second one involves using the homebrew program.
I also read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114213/how-can-i-pipe-commands-to-any-terminal), but it involves having a daemon run on tt7 expecting for my commands.
Isn't there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What matters is actually not what console you run the command from, but that you tell the program to connect to the still-existing X display. To do this, set the `DISPLAY` variable and restart Compiz from a standard terminal. Depending on your distribution and configuration, you may need to [set `XAUTHORITY`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#10126) as well. Switch to tty1 and type:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
$ compiz --replace &
```

The display may be different on your machine. Use `who` to find yours:

```
$ who
you     tty1    [time]             < This is you from tty1.
you     :0      [time] (:0)        < This is you from tty7.

        ^^              ^^
   This is your display on tty7
```

*Note: you must be logged in as yourself on tty7 (graphically). Fortunately, when Compiz crashes, you are not disconnected from tty7 (even though you can't do much).*

Comment: this doesn't seem to work or there is some other problem: `$compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core compiz (core) - Info: starting plugin: core` than it hangs. All this in the tty1 terminal

Comment: @Burdu I wouldn't expect to see anything else in the terminal. The new instance of Compiz is now running. What is the effect on the GUI? Maybe you need to [set `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28463/run-a-dbus-program-in-crontab-how-to-know-about-the-session-id/28496#28496) as well.

Comment: compiz does not get reloaded in tty7; nothing changes.