# dropbox process stops when I log out of ssh

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, init.d, dropbox

I tried every solution from [How to run Dropbox daemon in background?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35624/how-to-run-dropbox-daemon-in-background) and nothing solves my problem:

Basically, I already installed dropbox on my Ubuntu 12.04LTS headless server. I got init.d setup but the problem is that right now I cannot restart the server (other users are using it actively).

So I am trying to start dropbox via SSH which works and dropbox starts to sync, but as soon as I disconnect from SSH dropbox stops runnning. I tried running it on a detached screen, using `($HOME/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd &)&` and they all stop when I log out from SSH.

I tried doing service start but it seems not to work and I don't know why..?

```
$ sudo service dropbox start
[sudo] password: 
Starting dropbox...
$ dropbox status
Dropbox isn't running!
```

I followed the instructions:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/dropbox 
sudo update-rc.d dropbox defaults
```

from http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/install-dropbox-in-an-entirely-text-based-linux-environment#debianubuntu and I got no error messages. Please help.

I don't care as much about starting the process at server restart, as long as I can launch dropbox via ssh and keep it runnning after i log out.

Thank you

UPDATE & ANSWER: thanks a lot for all your answers. Thanks to user [Nixgrrrl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/146799/nixgrrrl)'s comment, I realize that it was because I was using ssh -X (the default on my system). As soon as I did normal ssh, trying the humble `dropbox start &` worked :)

Comment: You can also do a disown -a after.

Comment: `nohup $HOME/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd &

disown`
didn't work: after i logout from SSH it stops dropbox :(
note: disown was on another line (another command from the first one)

Comment: I remember wrestling w/ dropbox like this too. I wrote up this A over on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708715/check-if-program-is-running-with-bash-shell-script/9271229#9271229. Notice how I start dropbox there: `dropbox start -i > /dev/null`. Does that help here? Try starting it like that and backgrounding it and then disowning it or running it w/ `nohup`. I don't use `dropbox` anymore really so have no way to replicate this now.

Comment: I have been fighting this problem since I rebuilt my OS. I found out that if I disabled X11-tunneling in the SSH session, that dropbox will start and continue to run after I log off. It's like the process attaches to X11 and when I close out of the ssh session, it kills it. Hope this helps someone else . . .

Comment: Oh, that is very interesting. My ssh is by default using X, so maybe that's why nothing worked!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks a lot for all your answers. Thanks to user [Nixgrrrl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/146799/nixgrrrl)'s comment, I realize that it was because I was using ssh -X (the default on my system). As soon as I did normal ssh, trying the humble `dropbox start &` worked :)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here:

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/131973-dropbox-headless-workstation?page=1#entry-6076539

A user mentioned:

> Just thought I'd mention:
>
> (a) the latest distributions seem to make this fairly straightfoward,
>   just run `dropbox start` from the command line, BUT (b) watch out for
>   logging in and out with X11 forwarded.
>
> I've set up a lot of Bash aliases for connecting to various machines,
>   and they all include the `-X` option to forward X11 packets.  Because
>   of this, Dropbox kept dying on my on logout, even running it under
>   `screen` and with `nohup`.  Apparently, having X11 forwarded was causing
>   Dropbox to connect the dbus process on my local machine rather than on
>   the remote machine; so, when I broke the connection, Dropbox was
>   seeing dbus as having terminated and thus was terminating itself.
>
> Just FYI, as this stumped me for a bit.  The key was that I was having
>   to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> even after logging out / running `exit`
>   on the remote machine.  Apparently, SSH was keeping the session open, even
>   though I had exited Bash, because of the remaining open connection.

The solution is simple even if one (for some reason) wants to keep ssh-ing with the `-X`: before launching Dropbox you should "break" the forwarding for example doing:

```
$ unset DISPLAY
```

If this is done in a Bash script the forwarding is "broken" just inside the script but once this is executed the 'terminal' is still forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution would be to find the problem that avoids server starting from `service dropbox start`. Check your logs to see what's happened.

But in the mean time, you can start your daemon with `nohup`, that will keep it running after you logout.

`nohup $HOME/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd &`

Comment: thank you but `nohup $HOME/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd &` didn't work. same problem: as soon as I log out from SSH it kills dropbox. Where would the logs be please?

Comment: Start with /var/log, if no logs are there and dropbox is started as an unprivileged user, logs may be in your home directory. By the way, did you follow dropbox's installation guide? http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/install-dropbox-in-an-entirely-text-based-linux-environment