# /usr/bin/vim vs. /bin/vim

Tags: vim

I get that [binaries can be in different places](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux). What I don't understand is why when I run `whereis`, `which` and `type` it says `vim` is at `/usr/bin/vim`, but when I try to run it using `sudo` it says I can't run `/bin/vim`.

They are not links, and their content is the same. But ***I have persmission to perform `sudo` on `/usr/bin/vim`***, which is not being called **and I have no idea why!**

```
[user@host conf.d]$ sudo vim test.conf
[sudo] password for user: 
Sorry, user user is not allowed to execute '/bin/vim test.conf' as root on host.domain.com.br.
[user@host conf.d]$ whereis vim
vim: /usr/bin/vim /usr/share/vim /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz
[user@host conf.d]$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
[user@host conf.d]$ type vim
vim is /usr/bin/vim
[user@host conf.d]$ ll /bin/vi*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  910040 Jun 10 03:56 /bin/vi
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       2 Set 30 11:38 /bin/view -> vi
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2289656 Jun 10 03:56 /bin/vim
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       3 Set 30 12:14 /bin/vimdiff -> vim
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    2084 Jun 10 03:56 /bin/vimtutor
[user@host conf.d]$ ll /usr/bin/vi*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  910040 Jun 10 03:56 /usr/bin/vi
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       2 Set 30 11:38 /usr/bin/view -> vi
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2289656 Jun 10 03:56 /usr/bin/vim
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       3 Set 30 12:14 /usr/bin/vimdiff -> vim
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    2084 Jun 10 03:56 /usr/bin/vimtutor
[user@host conf.d]$ md5sum /usr/bin/vim
e5a9c498add4fa49a39a720a826f954c  /usr/bin/vim
[user@host conf.d]$ md5sum /bin/vim
e5a9c498add4fa49a39a720a826f954c  /bin/vim
[user@host conf.d]$
```

Comment: My bet would be on the sudo `PATH` preferring `/bin` over `/usr/bin`, or not even having `/usr/bin` in it. You can check with `sudo env | grep PATH`, if you have permission to run `sudo env`. Alternatively, if you can get into `sudo /usr/bin/vim`, you can run `:echo $PATH` from Vim.

Comment: @Bob Please put it into an answer and remember to mention the `secure_path` option in `/etc/sudoers` (also a compile time option).

Comment: P.S. This won't help with your problem, but the fact that the `ls` results from `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are identical makes me suspect that `/bin` is a symbolic link to `/usr/bin` (or vice versa).

Comment: I'd agree with @G-man. It's becoming increasingly common for distros to merge `/bin` into `/usr/bin` and symlink the former to the latter. You should check this.

Comment: If it's a symlink shouldn't it be shown with an `l` when I perform `ls`?

Comment: The symlink is `/bin` or `/usr/bin` or `/usr`, not `vim`.

Comment: @peterph Done. Sorry about the delay getting around to it.

Answer (score 4):

#### Some basics about search paths

When you run a command that does not contain slashes, such as `vim`, the shell needs to know which file (or shell builtin/function) to execute. It finds this by following the search path, defined in the `PATH` environment variable. The `PATH` variable is a list of paths separated by colons, and the shell will look for the command name within each of those paths in that order.

For example, a basic `PATH` from a Debian installation looks like the following:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

In this case, you find `/usr/bin/vim` first, as shown by the output of `which vim` and `type vim`.

Now, when you run a command via `sudo` where the `env_reset` and `secure_path` options are specified, `sudo` will reset the search path to the contents of `secure_path` before executing the command you pass it. This means that a command you run via `sudo` could have a *different* search path, and could find a different executable from running the command directly.

For example, a basic `sudo` `PATH` from Debian:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

---

#### Your scenario

What I suspect is happening here is your `secure_path` either specifies an order where `/bin` comes before `/usr/bin`, or the latter does not exist at all. In that case, the shell will look for `vim` and eventually find `/bin/vim`, since that exists. And if only `/usr/bin/vim` is whitelisted, then the former may not be allowed to run.

You can check your current `PATH` with `echo $PATH`. You can check your `sudo`'s `PATH` with `sudo env | grep PATH`. If your admin has set whitelists only allowing `vim`, then you can go into `sudo vim` and run the command `:echo $PATH`.

You should be able to get around it by specifying an absolute path, i.e. `sudo /usr/bin/vim`.

---

#### Why does `secure_path` exist?

As for *why* `sudo` sets a different path, consider this attack scenario:

Your `PATH` is just an environment variable. It can be set in many different ways, possibly invisible to the user. You could have insecure directories in it that allow anyone to write to them. If someone creates a malicious executable file named something like `ls`, then when you run `ls` you'd be executing this file instead of the real `ls`.

But the damage would be limited to what your account has access to. Now, say you run `sudo ls` - if the `PATH` is taken from your current `PATH` rather than being reset, then you've now run a malicious executable with root privileges - a privilege escalation attack. Far more possible damage than just running as your own user.

Now, you can argue that an attacker with the ability to place files in your `PATH` or otherwise modify your `PATH` can already do a lot of damage. And you're probably right. There's opinions on both sides about the usefulness of `secure_path`, which I won't get into here.