# How is install different from cp?

Tags: software-installation, cp, file-copy

How is [`install`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/install) different from a simple copy, [`cp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp) or [`dd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd)?  I just compiled a little utility and want to add it to `/usr/sbin` so it becomes available via my `PATH` variable.  Why use one vs the other?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To "install" a binary compiled from source the best-practice would be to put it under the directory:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

On some  systems that path is already in your PATH variable, if not you can add it by adapting the PATH variable in one of your profile configuration files `~/.bashrc ~/.profile`

```
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin
```

`dd` is a low level copy tool that is mostly used to copy exactly sized blocks of the source which could be for example a file or a device.

`cp` is the  common command to copy files and directories also recursively with the option `-r` and by preserving the permissions with the option `-p`.

`install` is mostly similar to `cp` but provides additionally the option to set the destination file properties directly without having to use `chmod` separately.

`cp` your files to `/usr/local/bin` and adapt the `PATH` variable if needed. That's what I would do.

Comment: If you're interested in why you should put it under /usr/local/ there is a pretty good answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux

Comment: In fact if you look at `man 1 install` you will find that there are a good many options that can be used when installing a file. For example, you can check if the file already exists, if so you can check if they are duplicate files and abort the install if the file is already installed. Configure mode, ownership and many other features all with a single  command.

Answer (score 20):

The primary difference between `install` and `cp` is that if the destination file already exists `install` unlinks it first.

This difference is not pointed out in the manual pages. The things listed in the other answers also matter -- both programs have different options, and also GNU `install` has different options than BSD `install` so portable Makefiles are limited to a common subset.

Why unlinking (which can be also done by `rm` before `cp`) matters? If you have a file with two hardlinks and modify it using one of the hardlinks, it's modified also in the other place on the filesystem. But if you remove one of the hardlinks first and replace it with modified file, the other place keeps the original version.

More probable scenario is that you update a program or a library while it is in use. If the binary is unlinked first, it won't affect the running program. Here is a nice post with more details:
http://en.chys.info/2009/05/install-vs-cp-and-mmap/

Comment: Archived link here: https://web.archive.org/web/20090624104441/http://en.chys.info/2009/05/install-vs-cp-and-mmap/

Answer (score 12):

Install copies files with the default mode 755.

Install can be configured to set the owner or group of a file and/or the mode of a file.

Install can be configured to backup the original file before it is replaced.

Comment: Assuming you're using the GNU versions, `cp` supports backups as well.

Comment: Upvoted -- best answer to this thread hands down