# Difference between /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin

Tags: directory, executable

What is the difference between `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`?

Why are there both directories and **why do some executable programs exist in both directories**?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux

Answer (score 33):

**`/usr/bin`** : contains executable programs that are part of the operating system and installed by its package manager

**`/usr/local/bin`** : default location for executable programs not part of the operating system and installed there by the local administrator, usually after building them from source with the sequence `configure;make;make install`. The goal is not to break the system by overwriting a functional program by a dysfunctional or one with a different behavior.

When the same program exists in both directories, you can select which ones will be called by default by rearranging the order of the directories in your `PATH`.

Comment: Why do some programs exist in both directories?

Comment: Precisely because there is one version part of the OS and another one built locally, presumably a newer one but not necessarily.

Comment: `/usr/bin` also was a path for executables that are not part of the OS. This was in the 1970s and maybe it helps to understand that using  `/usr/local/bin` is repeating the mistakes from the 1970s.

Answer (score -1):

**/usr/bin** is general system-wide binaries that contains most of the executable files (i.e., ready-to-run programs) that are not needed for booting (i.e., starting) or repairing the system.

**/usr/local/bin** is for programs that a normal user may run.

Comment: Not my downvote but you probably want to rephrase at least your last sentence. `/usr/bin` is also for programs that a normal user may run. By the way, "not normal" users might equally run whatever they choose to.