# Which of /usr/bin/perl or /usr/local/bin/perl should be used?

Tags: perl, executable

If I have both `/usr/bin/perl` and `/usr/local/bin/perl` available on a system, which one should I use?

Answer (score 5):

It depends: on some systems, e.g. BSD packaging, `/usr/local/bin` may be the directory where packages install executables.  In that case, it would be newer (and perhaps better), but `/usr/bin/perl` would be more stable.

You can use `perl -V` to see which has a newer version number.  Sometimes the contents of `/usr/local/bin` (on multi-user systems) isn't really newer.

The usual compromise is to let the user decide, by using `env` in the shebang/hashbang line (but again, the *path* to `env` can vary by system).
The shebang line refers to the first line of a script, which may look like one of the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

The first two specify the directory from which to run Perl.  As a bonus, this form allows passing an option, e.g. `-w` (used to turn on warnings).  The last line uses the `env` program to pick the first occurrence of `perl` by searching the directories listed in the user's `PATH` environment variable.

It is also possible to run a script like this:

```
perl myscript
```

which (like `env`) tells the shell to pick the first occurrence of `perl` from the directories listed in `PATH`.

An explicit

```
./perl myscript
```

of course overrides the `PATH`.  But scripts with shebang lines are the way most people use Perl scripts (Perl one-liners are a different matter).

Further reading:

- [/usr/bin/env perl - query](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=716740), referring to shebang line
- [/usr/bin vs /usr/local/bin on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux)
- [pkg(7)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&sektion=7), FreeBSD package system with `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: If I run `perl` from my home directory, which `perl` will be executed?

Comment: @CJ7 Run `type perl` or `command -v perl` to find out

Comment: @muru What setting causes which `perl` to be the one that is executed?

Comment: @CJ7 as Thomas has already said, the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: This is the first time I've heard of the shebang referred to as a "hash-tag line"...

Comment: As other have said, `echo $PATH` should show you which location is used first.

Comment: To examine the PATH, I like to use `tr : '\n' <<<":$PATH"`

Comment: hashtag is a *neologism* when used in the sense @Bob is familiar. It's derived from one sense of the use of hashmark (with which some commenters also are apparently unfamiliar).  For examining the `PATH`, I use a [script](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:path) except when explaining how `PATH` works. ymmv.

Answer (score 0):

Who is it for? If it is just you, as long as both your versions of perl are new enough it does not matter. Is it for a work environment? If so check your deployment policies as they may have the answer. If it is for distribution to the general public, I would recommend varying based upon package type, specifically use /usr/bin/perl for debs (per the debian guidelines) and rpms (as Red Hat specifically disallows rpms to install to /usr/local), but /usr/bin/env perl for tar and shar packages as it has the best chance of working on random unix computers.