# Unable to get systemd to active status

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, daemon

I'm trying to use systemd on Ubuntu 16.04 to run a python 3 process. I've been following the article [How to Install and Configure Supervisor on Ubuntu 16.04](https://cloudwafer.com/blog/how-to-install-and-configure-supervisor-on-ubuntu-16-04/).

I'm unable to get the systemd service running - status command shows the following:

```
● supervisord.service - Supervisor daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/supervisord.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-02-13 12:39:03 UTC; 1s ago
     Docs: http://supervisord.org
  Process: 19911 ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl $OPTIONS shutdown (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
  Process: 19902 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf (code=exited, status=203/E
 Main PID: 19902 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

I don't know enough about systemd or linux to know what it means.

This is my service configuration `/etc/systemd/system/supervisord.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Supervisor daemon
Documentation=http://supervisord.org
After=network.target
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl $OPTIONS shutdown
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl $OPTIONS reload
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=42s
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=supervisord.service
```

Can anyone explain what's gone wrong and suggest how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The codes were not documented in the `systemd.exec` manual page back then, but they meant largely the same.  Code 203 means that there's something stopping a process from `execve()`ing the named executable program image file.  You should do the obvious thing and look to see whether the program image files are even there.

My educated guess is that you installed with APT, as the tutorial said.  Think about where APT packages install stuff.  The company whose tutorial you are following apparently did not.

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering (2017).  "[Process exit codes: systemd-specific exit codes](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#id-1.20.8)".  *systemd.exec*.  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/supervisor
- [/usr/bin vs /usr/local/bin on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8656/5132)

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer and the info. Truth be told, I'm not sure I understand from this where to look. Even if I did know where they were installed (and I've partially struggled to find out), I'm not sure what to do with this info. From what you say the tutorial I'm following would seem to be out of date. Perhaps with my level of linux knowledge I will try to find a more up to date guide.